# Showing that a set union is the smallest set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show that $A\cup B$ is the smallest set containing both $A$ and $B$ in the sense that it is contained in every such set.

I am not sure how to show that $A\cup B$ is the smallest set. It seems very trivial to me. I realize that if $A\cup B \subseteq$ of every set containing $A$ and $B$ then it is indeed the smallest. How can that be done?

I start my attempt at the proof by:

Let $S$ be a set containing $A$ and $B$.

Then I don't now where to go

Comment: You need to show that $A\cup B\subseteq S$. So choose an element $x\in A\cup B$. Then $x\in A$ or $x\in B$. If $x\in A$, then $x\in S$ since ... can you finish the proof?

Comment: Yes this makes sense now. If $A \cup B \subseteq S$ it implies exactly what I wanted to show. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your start seems okay to me.

Let $S$ be a set that contains $A$ and $B$ in the sense that $A\subseteq S$ and $B\subseteq S$.

Now let $x\in A\cup B$.

Then $x\in A$ or $x\in B$ wich implies in both cases $x\in S$.

This proves that $x\in S$ and can be shown for *each* $x\in A\cup B$.

We conclude that $A\cup B\subseteq S$.